# In Eclipse I was successfully pulled my Code from Git, but I could See ">" without making any changes to my Local directory

Tags: eclipse, git, github

In Eclipse I was successfully pulled my Code from Git, but I could See ">" without making any changes to my Local directory..Is it I am making some error in pulling the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you describe which specific files are marked as locally changed (">")?

Depending on your repository contents and view settings, I imagine they are files that Eclipse or its plugins generate, such as ".project".

Eclipse IDE uses certain files to record your project settings (".project") and other information about your project such as its Java classpath (".classpath"). By default these files are filtered out and not displayed by Eclipse views such as the Package Explorer. But those filter settings can be changed.

If these same files are stored in your git repository, and if there are any further modifications to those settings within the Eclipse IDE, then the files may become marked as modified since the last commit (">").

Because you did not directly change their contents in a text editing window, and may not even have been aware that they were present at all, you could perhaps be surprised when they show up as locally modified files in a view such as the Package Explorer or the Synchronize View.

Comment: mionpret Could you explain me in detail..?? thanks in advance

Comment: There are Random files which are having ">" not specifically ".project" or ".Classpath" files..